# Resizing an image to fit around an isolated object in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bounding-box, binary-image

I am working with RGB images that contain a single object against a monochrome background.

My goal is to isolate the object in the image and resize the image to contain only the object.

I have successfully been able to detect the object by converting the image to a binary image using an appropriate threshold. Then, in order to isolate the object in the original RGB image I use the binary image as a mask with the original RGB image.

```
maskedImage = bsxfun(@times,originalimage, cast(binaryimage,class(originalimage)));
```

This leaves me with a image only containing the object surrounded by a black background. This is due to the fact that the binary image mask I used contained the object in white pixels and the background in black pixels and since possess intensity values of 0 the masking process converted all pixels that didn't belong to the object to black pixels. I've attached an example below.

[image: two muppets]

I would now like to draw a bounding box around the object and resize the image to the size of the bounding box, so that I can get rid as much of the surrounding black pixels as possible. Is there any way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your problem statement.  Can you show us image examples and/or code to demonstrate what it is you're talking about?  From what I gathered, instead of having a mask that is of an arbitrary shape, you would like to use a square instead, but this may lead to introducing background pixels into the mask. Is this what you want?  Please share with us some code that you've done so far to illustrate your point.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it makes more sense now. I think what I'm asking is much simpler than that :)

Comment: Oh I see.  You basically want to **crop** the image so that it only contains the object, and none of the background, yes?

Comment: Actually, it would be one step shorter to find the bounding box of the binary image.

Comment: Yes! But since the objects aren't rectangular, removing as much of the background will do just fine

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the segmented image, you want to crop out all of the black pixels and provide the closest bounding box that fully encapsulates the object.  That's very simple.

You already have a binary mask that determines what is an object and what's background.  You simply need to find the minimum spanning bounding box.  You can find the top-left and bottom right corner by obtaining all of the pixel locations that are non-zero in the mask, and finding the minimum and maximum row and column coordinates.  You'd then just use these to crop out the segmented image.

As such:

```
%// Find all non-zero locations in the mask
[row,col] = find(binaryImage);

%// Find the top left corner of the mask
topLeftRow = min(row);
topLeftCol = min(col);

%// Find the bottom right corner of the mask
bottomRightRow = max(row);
bottomRightCol = max(col);

%// Extract the object
extracted = maskedImage(topLeftRow:bottomRightRow, topLeftCol:bottomRightCol, :);
```

Comment: Thanks so much again. You've helped me out with so much so far. All the questions are for an intelligent optical sorter I'm trying to design in MATLAB.

Comment: @user2802349 no problem at all.  I love image processing problems and algorithms.  Keep asking!

Answer (score 1):

The words of the day are *Bounding boxes* !

If you want the minimum-area rectangle to crop only the nonzero values, you want the bounding box of your region, then set your phasers to stun and you're all set !

See this [Matlab help forum question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/87597-rectangle-around-the-object-bounding-box) for more implementation details in Matlab.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  You don't know when those links will expire.  Instead, take crucial points from the post, put them in your answer, and provide a link as a reference.

Comment: Also, that MathWorks link is not the correct answer.  That only draws a rectangle spanning the object onto the image.  It doesn't crop out the bounding box spanning the object.

Comment: Dang, wanted to write skeleton answer before adding more meat to it. But question was edited and commented on since then, making answer moot. Should I delete that ?

Comment: Ahhh... no you can leave it.  Bounding boxes is indeed the correct answer, but I would probably remove the reference to the MathWorks post.  That post doesn't answer the OP's question.